# Error compiling MVC 3 project after adding FacebookWebMvc Nuget Package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk, nuget

I added the FacebookWebMvc Nuget package to my MVC 3 Web Application project and then created the following controller:

```
public ActionResult FacebookLogOn(string returnUrl)
{
    if (!FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        throw new Exception("Please log into facebook");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error (with the FacebookWebContext highlighted as the source of the error):

The type 'Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext' exists in both 'I:\sites\ICTOAD\packages\FacebookWeb.5.0.26.0\lib\net40\Facebook.Web.dll' and 'I:\sites\ICTOAD\packages\FacebookWeb.5.0.26.0\lib\net40\CodeContracts\Facebook.Web.Contracts.dll'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove a reference to `Facebook.Web.Contracts.dll` from your project.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! Should the nuget package be updated to not add that dll reference?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember, I just did it once; I believe I just got facebook web from nuget manager console and it worked.

Comment: Okay, I also had to remove the references to Facebook.Contracts.dll and Facebook.Web.Mvc.Contracts.dll, but that did it.

Comment: which version of facebook are you using. it is supposed to remove the *Contratcs.dll file if not could you file a bug.

Comment: @prabir I'm using version 5.0.26.0 (the latest at this time). I'll file a bug.